# Get Experience Forms Response Statistics using API

Tags: sitecore-api, sitecore-forms

In a Sitecore Form for example if I have list of questions with list of radio button answers. Does Sitecore have an API to return the statistics of how many users choose this answer?

I'm using Sitecore 9.3

Comment: Perhaps use this to export the data. You could modify to run the calculations. https://gist.github.com/michaellwest/3894cc032b33f0330c0a56b6a1bdf511

Answer (score 0):

Sitecore doesn't have an API to return statistics of how many users choose this answers,

but it has a function to get all results from a form :

```
 IEnumerable<FormEntry> formEntries = this._formDataProvider.GetEntries(formId, startDate, endDate).AsEnumerable<FormEntry>();
```

You need to build your own controller and to inject formDataProvider on it.

Please have a look on class :  **Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Client.Data.CsvExportProvider**